# rich:calendar expanding fails in IE8 because of cache

Tags: richfaces

I have faced strange problem with rich:calendar in IE8. When I click on calendar without clearing browser cache, I receive javascript exception:

```
Message: 'elements' is null or not an object
```

And browser points to following function in **3_3_2.SR1org.ajax4jsf.javascript.PrototypeScript** file:

```
bindAsEventListener: function () {
    var __method = this, args = $A(arguments), object = args.shift();
    return function (event) {
        return __method.apply(object, [event || window.event].concat(args));
    }
```

The most interesting is that when I clear browser cache and reload the page, calendar works!

P.S. Version of Richfaces is 3.3.2.SR1, and I am not authorized to upgrade it

Answer (score 0):

After some investigation it appeared that the problem was caused by conflict of PIE.js and Richfaces calendar component. And this is not the first time (I also experienced problems with rounded-corners button on rich:panel). Anyway, if you will face something similar - be careful:)